# Unable to create signed release APK for android

Tags: android, react-native

I made a project on react-native. All was working fine and whenever I create debug apk it also worked always. but now I have to create a signed release apk to deploy it on google play store. For that I created a keystore file with command `keytool -genkey -v -keystore ENTER_APP_Name.keystore -alias ENTER_APP_Alias_Name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`. I added keystore details to build.gradle as
    `....
    android {
    ....
      signingConfigs { 
        release { 
          storeFile file('your_key_file_name.keystore') 
          storePassword 'your_key_store_password' 
          keyAlias 'your_key_file_alias' 
          keyPassword 'your_key_file_alias_password' 
        } 
      }
      buildTypes {
        release {
          ....
          signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
      }
    }
    ....`
and added the keystore file to android/app/app.keystore
After something strange happened with me. Some times `react-native run-android` gives error, Sometimes debug APK gives and all the time release apk giving one or two error, each time it is different.
I tried to create release apk with two methods.
1. with terminal : inside the project folder : 
 `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file
    index.android.js --bundle-output
    android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest
    android/app/src/main/res`

then `cd android`
then `gradlew assembleRelease`

2. with android studio : build > generate signed apk > select apk then next then added keystore details then select release option and then finish.

These both methods gave me different errors but randomly not all together. I have mentioned them following :
1. Task :app:processReleaseResources FAILED( Android resource linking failed)
2. Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED( Android resource linking failed)
3. Android resource linking failed
4.app\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\release\AndroidManifest.xml:17: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.app:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.
5. app\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\release\AndroidManifest.xml:17: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher_round (aka com.app:mipmap/ic_launcher_round) not found.
6. error: failed processing manifest.

And If I get the release app without any error then It does not allow me to cross the login screen, It gives me an error alert which normally comes when api doesn't respond or when server is down.

Answer (score 0):

There is one thing to check for sure. It says that you are missing a launcher icon (this `ic_launcher` thing). Maybe check if it is referenced anywhere in the project try to fix that first and check if something changes in the errors situation. You've got clear instruction that it is missing. Hope that helps you. Have a good day!

Comment: OK, will try that. Thanks.